# jQuery Ajax Background Process

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have to process a large image file and I'd like to set this process in motion than have the user be able to continue on with other things. If I make an AJAX call with:
`async: true`, can I redirect the users to another page and that function will continue on the server until finished?

Comment: When you redirect, the HTTP connection is closed. The server might kill the process, so you can't depend on it continuing.

Comment: The nature of asynchronous AJAX is to allow users continue with other things (on the same page) while the server-side process is in progress. 
You neither want nor need to redirect to another page.

Comment: There are several things in the AJAX call that I do need to show the user, but it would be nice if the final image processing could be left to process in the background without the user having to wait for it to finish. But I don't want to risk the process not being completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you redirect to another url, the server kill the process!
If you want to do image processing on the server, its a different story, but if you want to do it on the browser, you can do it in the background, but you have to just stay in the same page and url. if you change the page or url, you will lost it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But if the PHP function was set in motion on the server, will it still finish what it started?

Comment: No, I'm not sure if there is a library for php to do that, but if you want to do such thing I recommend you node js (express). it is really better for this.